# JavaFX inline CSS hover effect

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I am building a costume button by extending from a Label.
I know that you can use CSS within .java files with:

```
setStyle("-fx-background-color: #101010");
```

which is pretty cool and I am using this quite often.

But there is my problem: It seems like this doesn't work for hover effects.
In an external CSS file you can have:

```
#LabelButton:hover {
  -fx-background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

I would like to have this feature with "XXX:hover" inside my Java File because the hex color code must be variable and this isn't possible when using external CSS files. So what I kinda want to have it this:

```
setStyle("hover:-fx-background-color: #101010");
```

But I can't find the right syntax for it let alone there is a syntax.
If there is no such feature, how should I do it then?
Thanks!

Comment: From a purist's point of view it would be cleaner to assign classes and ids and have the css in a separate file. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I know, I know.
But as I said, it wont work for me because I need to make the hex color code variable

Comment: If your problem is with external CSS files, you can also put the CSS in a <style> element.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to use selectors of any kind in inline CSS. The inline style is always applied to the node regardless of it's state (with the exception of you assigning the corresponding node property).

You could bind the `style` property to the `hover` property of the node.

```
myButton.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.when(myButton.hoverProperty())
                                      .then("-fx-background-color: #101010")
                                      .otherwise("-fx-background-color: #aaaaaa"));
```

This could become very ugly if you e.g. want to style focused buttons and pressed buttons differently. For this reason I recommend combining CSS and inline CSS to achieve the desired style:

You can define your own variables color variables in CSS:

#### stylesheet

```css
.label-button { /* using style class for selector (ids are for single nodes) */
    /* assign default values */
    -fx-normal-background: yellow;
    -fx-hovered-background: red;

    -fx-background-color: -fx-normal-background;
}

.label-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-hovered-background;
}
```

#### java code

```
myButton.setStyle("-fx-normal-background: #101010; -fx-hovered-background: #aaaaaa;");
```